# S3 and Filepicker.io - Multi-file, zipped download on the fly

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, filepicker.io

I am using Ink (Filepicker.io) to perform multi-file uploads and it is working brilliantly.

However, a quick look around the internet shows multi-file downloads are more complicated. While I know it is possible to spin up an EC2 instance to zip on the fly, this would also entail some wait-time on the user's part, and the newly created file would also not be available on my Cloudfront immediately.

Has anybody done this before, and what are the practical UX implications - is the wait time significant enough to negatively affect the user experience?

The obvious solution would be to create the zipped files ahead of time, but this would result in some (unnecessary?) redundancy.

What is the best way to avoid redundant storage while reducing wait times for on-the-fly folder compression?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the ZIP archive on the client side using JavaScript. Check out:

http://stuk.github.io/jszip/

Comment: @snakesNbronies - How did you get on with JSZip?

Comment: This was for a one-off project. However, I ended up passing the arguments to EC2, zipping the files on the fly, and then exporting via filepicker.  While this was going on, I asked the user to keep browsing, and would raise a client-side notification to click "download" when the file was ready to serve.  In total, the wait time wasn't significant in most cases (~10-20 seconds at most), but rather than force the user to wait at a given page for that long, I thought the UX would be improved by notifying of the download being available asynchronously.